# Navigation controller isn't working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am using navigation controller for connecting 8 form page to each other. According to users choice it is navigating next screen using following code :

```
    if (GlobalVariable.page[0] == true || GlobalVariable.page[1] == true || GlobalVariable.page[2] == true || GlobalVariable.page[3] == true) {            
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var destinationVC:UIViewController!
        destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstInfo") as! FirstInfoVC
        navigationController?.show(destinationVC, sender: self)
    }
```

When I use above code user can go previous screen using swipe left gesture. It is okay until now. However, every page has menu button and after filled 8 page or whenever they wants user can click that menu button and according to choice it needs to navigate the another view controller independent from that 8 page. For navigating that independent view controller I am also trying to use above code in my menu table view didselectrowat function but it is not working (actually, it is doing nothing). What could be the reason of it and how can I fix it?

**Edit :** 
In my side navigation controller class

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let menu = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewController") as! MenuTableViewController
    sideMenu = ENSideMenu(sourceView: self.view, menuViewController: menu, menuPosition: .left)
    sideMenu?.menuWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8
    sideMenu?.bouncingEnabled = false

    //Navigation Bar Özelleştirmesi İçin Renk Mavi Üstüne Beyaz
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.47, blue:0.74, alpha:1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]

    view.bringSubview(toFront: navigationBar)
}
```

and in my menu table view code is following:

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var destinationVC:UIViewController!

        if (indexPath.row == 2) {

            destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "independentPage") as? IndependentVC
                navigationController?.show(destinationVC, sender: self)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: show ALL of the relevant code.. `didSelect` implementation, setting the delegate, etc.

Comment: why are you creating new instance of UIStoryboard ? you can just use self.storyboard. Aren't you using storyboards ?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I have added it and because it is navigation controller I did not give any delegate.

Comment: @harshayarabarla Should not I create it shall I create once in a static then use for everywhere ?

Comment: @AtalayAsaif you are using storyboards then you can get the instance directly by self.storyboard . Here new instance of Storyboard is created every time and all views are reset to initial states.